# java/oracle exception--Non supported character set

Tags: java, sql, oracle, character-encoding, oracle11g

e have configuration as java 1.5, oracle 11g and tomcat 5 server running and getting the exception as mentioned below. any solution would be helpful:

```
user_lname=TEST LAST NAME,email=,usertypes=BILLER|MS_ACCT_ASSOCIATE|PILOT,hr_org_code=,sales_cbu=,sales_team=) from request headers] ==> 2012-03-29 11:09:04,602 (+00:00:00,039) - NDC = [<mrsxport,EMETERS1,1A48AA5D84E103C1BFD9382966CBA316>]
==> 2012-03-29 11:09:04,603 (+00:00:00,040) - requestURL = []
     Error Message: Unexpected exception during generic page setup!
                    An exception occurred while execute the [get_header_data] CallableStatementProcedure!
                    **java.sql.SQLException: Non supported character set: oracle-character-set-178**
                        at oracle.gss.util.NLSError.throwSQLException(NLSError.java:46)
                        at oracle.sql.CharacterSetUnknown.failCharsetUnknown(CharacterSetFactoryThin.java:171)
                        at oracle.sql.CharacterSetUnknown.toString(CharacterSetFactoryThin.java:128)
                        at oracle.xdb.XMLType.processString(XMLType.java:1101)
                        at oracle.xdb.XMLType.processThin(XMLType.java:1136)
                        at oracle.xdb.XMLType.<init>(XMLType.java:541)
                        at oracle.xdb.XMLType.createXML(XMLType.java:344)
                        at com.xerox.xcs.common.ssf.procmgr.jdbc.CallableStatementProcedure.generateXMLOutputParameter(CallableStatementProcedure.java:751)
                        at com.xerox.xcs.common.ssf.procmgr.jdbc.CallableStatementProcedure.generateXMLResponse(CallableStatementProcedure.java:696)
                        at com.xerox.xcs.common.ssf.procmgr.jdbc.CallableStatementProcedure.getNewContent(CallableStatementProcedure.java:406)
                        at com.xerox.xcs.common.ssf.procmgr.jdbc.CallableStatementProcedure.execute(CallableStatementProcedure.java:220)
                        at com.xerox.xcs.common.ssf.procmgr.jdbc.CallableStatementProcedure.execute(CallableStatementProcedure.java:147)
                        at com.xerox.xcs.mrsxport.struts.AbstractGotoPageAction.getHeaderData(AbstractGotoPageAction.java:156)
                        at com.xerox.xcs.mrsxport.struts.AbstractGotoPageAction.execute(AbstractGotoPageAction.java:76)
                        at com.xerox.xcs.mrsxport.struts.GotoViewHistoryPageAction.execute(GotoViewHistoryPageAction.java:64)
                        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:421)
                        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:226)
                        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1164)
                        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:397)
                        at com.xerox.xcs.common.web.struts.SSFBaseActionServlet.doGet(SSFBaseActionServlet.java:189)
                        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:627)
                        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
                        at org.apache.catalina.core.Appl
```

Comment: I have seen something similar on mysql. I was trying to store hebrew characters into text and varchar fields, and I got an illegal character set exception. The fix was to set the character sets for my columns, and also (I think) to set the default character set for the database.

Answer (score 0):

What is the database character set and national character set

```
SELECT *
  FROM v$nls_parameters
 WHERE parameter LIKE '%CHARACTERSET'
```

What sort of data are you trying to store and/ or retrieve (i.e. English, Hebrew, Japanese, etc.)?  What is the character set of the page?

Comment: Query Result:      
 "NLS_CHARACTERSET WE8MSWIN1252
  NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16"                                                                                                                                   and the Line which gave exception is :
"if (type.startsWith("OracleTypes")) {
if (type.equals("OracleTypes.OPAQUE:SYS.XMLTYPE")) {
OPAQUE opaque = cstmt.getOPAQUE(pos);"  

Code was before developed in java1.4 and oracle 10g, now we are migrating to oracle 11g and java5

Comment: @Sachi - What was the character set and national character set of the old 10g database?  What is the encoding of the XML file you are trying to store?

Comment: Justin, oracle 10g character set was:                                            "NLS_CHARACTERSET US7ASCII
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16"                                                            But not sure on the XML encoding type, it creates dynamically.

Comment: By default it creates XML encoding type will be "encoding="UTF-8""